# SOA architecture for ASP.NET with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, wcf, visual-studio-2008, entity-framework, soa

I am redesigning a solution's architecture to implement [SOA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture).

After doing the design changes I have come up with:

- MySolution.Client.MyProject.Web ...... //ASP.NET WebSite
- MySolution.Client.MyProject.Proxy .... //Service Proxy C# Library Project *[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture)
- MySolution.Service ................... //Service.cs for Service.svc is here
- MySolution.Service.DataContract ...... //IService.cs for Service.cs is here *[2]
- MySolution.Service.HttpHost .......... //Service.svc is here
- MySolution.Model ..................... //All custom data classes and EDMX model is here *[3]
- MySolution.Repository ................ //Repository queries the DB using LINQ and ADO.NET queries

***[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture) MySolution.Client.MyProject.Proxy:**
This project contains service proxy and contains presentation classes

***[2]MySolution.Service.DataContract:**

- This project contains IService and Request/Response Classes
- All methods in Service.cs takes the Request classes as input and return Response classes as output
- Therefore this project is referenced by the 2 Client Projects(Web and Proxy), as it contains the IService and all of the Request/Response classes that will be required to communicate with Service.cs

***[3]MySolution.Model:**
This project contains the .edmx that is the Data Model of Entity Framework and some custom classes that are used in the project.

**PROBLEM:**

Because I only use request/response classes to communicate between service and client, the *MySolution.Service.DataContract* project is only used by Service.cs and Repository.cs

And due to that all responses that Repository generates I have to map them to the properties of its respective response class (which make both the original returned entity, and the response class almost identical). But I am OKAY with it...

For example:

- The GetCustomer() in Repository.cs method is called by Service.cs
- The GetCustomer() method in repository performs the LINQ query and returns a "Customer" object
- Service.cs then maps all the properties of "Customer" object to the "CustomerResponse" object
- Service.cs then returns the "CustomerResponse" to the caller.

In this case, most of the properties will repeat in both classes. If there is a solution to this, it's good, otherwise, I am fine with it.

However, when Repository.cs's method GetCustomers() (*Notice it's not GetCustomer()*) is called, it will return a list of Customer objects, and mapping this for return purposes would mean a "for loop" that iterates the collection and do the mapping... This is NOT OKAY...

Is there a better way of doing this, considering I do not want to return "Customer" object without "CustomerResponse" as first of all it violates the SOA architecture, and secondly I don't want my client projects to have any reference to the Model or Repository projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So is it just the mapping that you're having trouble with? If so, you could look at some open source mapping libraries like [Mapper Extensions](http://mapperextensions.codeplex.com/documentation) or [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) that will automate the task.

Comment: Yeh, the main issue is Mapping, plus also, I have to create exactly the same classes to create a Response class again; although the classes are already generated by the Entity Framework ... by the way is it a good approach to inherit the Response class fromEntityFramework generated class? I am not sure if that will inherit only the properties, or will inherit all other functionality, such as when new object is created, and the Save method is called, it adds new row in DB ... ???

Comment: Well I guess maybe I should understand why you're using the response objects in the first place before I answer...are you just trying to abstract the physical data structure?

Comment: yeh, in most cases, but in other, i add few extra properties functionality as well

Comment: Well inheriting from the Entity Framework classes will work just fine, but yes, you will get all functionality. If I were you I would use the POCO Entity T4 template. That way your object context is separated from your data objects. You can then derive from these objects if that makes sense, or instantiate them within your response objects and expose them via a property. That with the ability to map to and from your response objects should fix your problem. http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/23df0450-5677-4926-96cc-173d02752313

Comment: mmmm ... that looks good ... i'll try that over the weekend, and probably get back if am stuck ... for now i think it answers the question. (any other suggestion ... regarding my architecture ?? ... as this is the first time I am implementing SOA ... after reading the book "ASP.NET Design Patterns") ... just to let you know more about the architecture: there are 5 client Applications, that are accessing the underlying Repository/Model through their respective services.

Comment: Correction: sorry, the underlying repositories are different for each client app, and the model project as well ....

Comment: The biggest challenges you will have in implementing a SOA is how to break down business logic/requirements into services. This can be tricky if you're new to SOA. You should break down your system based on areas of volatility, or areas of greatest change. Try not to have services been too coarse or fine grained, but instead look for a sweet spot in the middle. From what you are describing, it sounds more like integration than true SOA. Good luck!

Comment: @Brandon thanks for suggesting Mapper Extensions.  I checked in a new version this morning, introducing a fluid API. You might want to check it out :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your main point of grief is the tedious mapping of data objects to [data transfer objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) (DTOs). I haven't used this myself, but it seems like [AutoMapper](http://www.bengtbe.com/blog/post/2009/04/14/Using-AutoMapper-to-map-view-models-in-ASPNET-MVC.aspx) is made for doing automatic object-to-object mappings declaratively.

I would definitely stick to having your data objects separate from the data contracts in your services.

Comment: please see the comment i made on BrandonZeider's post below

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like separate mapping between entities and DTOs expose `IQueryable` in your repository and use direct projections to DTOs. The disadvantage is that such solution can't be effectively unit tested. Mocking repository in such scenario doesn't make sense because query agains mock is Linq-to-objects whereas query against real repository is Linq-to-entities (different set of features where difference can be seen only at runtime).

Btw. I don't see too much SOA in your application - I see just multi tier application. It is like planting a tree in a garden and saying that you have a forest. Moreover it sounds like you are building CRUD interface (entities almost 1:1 to DTOs). I have a bad feeling that you are investing too big effort to architecture which you don't need. If your main intention is to build CRUD operations exposed as services on top of database you can expose entities directly moreover you can use tools like [WCF Data services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668792.aspx).

Comment: Yeh in most cases it is entities are 1:1 to DTO, but not always. May be you are rite, i dont need SOA, but i still want to implement it, as i like the architecture and the way client communicates only through service. The Repository, Model projects are also used by 4 other client applications, using their separate Services, but the underlying Repository and Model are same across all 5 client applications.

Comment: what would be the best practice in this regard? i.e. (entities are 1:1 to DTO), shoudl i be creating the same DTO classes again?

Comment: 5 services to expose same repositories? Imho it is more against SOA then exposing entity itself. In SOA services should be independent = no shared features (including data) among services.

Comment: please read the comments under "BrandonZeider" post, and if you can suggest some thing that would be great, you can suggest here if you want ....

Comment: If your entity is serializable and if it is exactly the same as your DTO, you can use it directly. If you do not share the contract assembly between the service and the client it will not be violation of SOA because both your entity and DTO will be described as the same data contract in WSDL.